# Node.js Lambda Async return Undefined

Tags: node.js, lambda

Simple call to ec2 Describing Security groups and returning the security group ID. Using Async / await, but when logging the return value, I get undefined. I fully admit I'm coming from Python and I've tried my hardest to wrap my brain around async calls. I thought I had it nailed, but I'm obviously missing something.

```
'use strict';

// Load Modules
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

//Set the region
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});

// Call AWS Resources
const ec2 = new AWS.EC2();

// Get Security Group ID From Event
const getSgIdFromEvent = async (event) => {
  var ec2params = { Filters: [{Name: 'tag:t_whitelist',Values[event['site']]}]};
  await ec2.describeSecurityGroups(ec2params, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {return console.error(err.message)}
    else {
      var sgId = response.SecurityGroups[0].GroupId;
      return sgId;
    };
  });
 };
// MAIN FUNCTION
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  getSgIdFromEvent(event)
   .then(sgId => {console.log(sgId)});
}
```

"sgId" should return the security group ID. It does print out fine in the original function before the return.

Comment: Are you sure the method `describeSecurityGroups` returns a Promise? Usually functions that accept callbacks then don't use Promise, because they're two different ways to solve the same problem. So maybe you have to promisefy the callback

Comment: Here's a nice article which describes that in details:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-a-promise-out-of-a-callback-function-in-javascript-d8ec35d1f981

Comment: I also noticed that you was trying to return inside a callback. **NEVER** returns inside a callbacks expecting that the output will be availabe outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically if it is an async call you want you handle it similar to this way without using a callback

```
// Load Modules
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

//Set the region
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-west-2' });

// Call AWS Resources
const ec2 = new AWS.EC2();

// Get Security Group ID From Event
const getSgIdFromEvent = async (event) => {
    var ec2params = { Filters: [{ Name: 'tag:t_whitelist', Values[event['site']]}] };
    try {
        const securityGroupsDesc = await ec2.describeSecurityGroups(ec2params).promise();
        const sgId = securityGroupsDesc.SecurityGroups[0].GroupId;
        //do something with the returned result
        return sgId;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('handle error');
        // throw error;
    }
});
 };
// MAIN FUNCTION
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    getSgIdFromEvent(event)
        .then(sgId => { console.log(sgId) });
}
```

however if it doesn't support async you just use the callback to handle the returned data or error without using async function.However Reading into AWS docs you can find that the function ec2.describeSecurityGroups() returns an [AWS Request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html) 
which has a method [promise()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#promise-property) that needs to be invoked to send the request and get a promise returned.Note that the try catch here is not needed but good to have in case error occurs during the process.

Comment: Are you sure the method returns a promise? I don't know AWS enough well

Comment: @CristianTraìna I wasn't sure either but now that i had more time I just read into their AWS docs ,I updated the answer read the bottom section to see what it returns and how to get a promise from it.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, chance are that `describeSecurityGroups` doesn't return a `Promise`. Try transforming it explictly in a Promise instead:

```
const promiseResponse = await new Promise((res, rej) => {
  ec2.describeSecurityGroups(ec2params, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {return rej(err.message)}
    else {
      var sgId = response.SecurityGroups[0].GroupId;
      res(sgId);
    };
  })
});

// promiseResponse is now equal to sgId inside the callback
return promiseResponse; // this will work because the function is async
```

Note: You can drop the `else` keyword

Comment: You are correct in that my `ec2.describeSecurityGroups` doesn't return a promise it returns an _AWS Request_. Thank you! That led me down the proper road to get code that is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked using `async / await`. Thanks to @Cristian Traina I realized `ec2.describeSecurityGroups` wasn't returning a promise, it was returning an `AWS.Event`.

```
// Get Security Group ID From Event
const getSgIdFromEvent = async (event) => {
  console.log('Getting Security Group ID')
  var params = { Filters: [{Name: 'tag:t_whitelist', Values 
   [event['site']]}]};
  const describeSG = await ec2.describeSecurityGroups(params).promise();
  return describeSG.SecurityGroups[0].GroupId;
 };

// Get Ingress Rules from Security Group
const getSgIngressRules = async (sgId) => {
  console.log(`Getting SG Ingress rules for ${sgId}`)
  var params = { GroupIds: [ sgId]};
  try{
    const ingressRules = await ec2.describeSecurityGroups(params).promise();
    return ingressRules;
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log("Something went wrong getting Ingress Ruls");
  }
 };

// MAIN FUNCTION
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  getSgIdFromEvent(event)
  .then(sgId => {return getSgIngressRules(sgId);}) 
  .then(ingressRules => {console.log(ingressRules);});
}
```

I submitted this as the answer now since the `getSgIdFromEvent` function I have, is only 8 lines and still using the `async/await` like I was desiring.

What I was missing was the `.promise()` on the end of the function and returning that promise.

Thanks for all the responses!

Comment: Here you are using an async function but it's await still has a callback which is not how its meant to be , async is used to replace the callbacks see my updated answer above for a better solution where the callback taken off.

Comment: check the part where you pass a function as a callback in describeSecurityGroups to get err,response mine dosen't and its not needed at all when you use async function

Comment: I understand what you're saying now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you did :)